# How do I upgrade my duck?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So the new TF2 EOTL update features a thing called a duck, which you can equip. It says you can find ducks from fallen enemies and use them to upgrade your duck.

[image]

Now i"m a little confused because in the store there is a Duck Token, which also appears to level up the Duck. So what's the difference between just killing enemies to get ducks as opposed to getting Duck Tokens?

How do I level up, or upgrade my duck?

Comment: From reading the description in your image, all I see is that it says that Duck Tokens increase the power level. I don't see anything about any other duck things increasing the power level.

Comment: @murgatroid99 But duck tokens seem to only be available in the shop. Do I have to shell out $2.00 just to level up my token?

Comment: Sounds like you need to get your ducks in a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duck maintains it's own version of a kill streak (a duckstreak). Creating ducks, and picking up ducks gathers XP. If your XP reaches 5000, the duck will level up, and the XP will be reset to 0.

This works very similiar to strange weapons. When the duck levels up, it will get another title, just like a strange weapon does.

The Duck Tokens increase the amount of ducks dropped for each kill, objective, etc. This will allow you to level up your duck faster.

That's all there is to ducks. More can be found here: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Duck_Journal